# How to record the linux commands executed inside a Kubernetes Container?

Tags: kubernetes, containers, audit

For auditing purposes, if we need to record all the linux commands that have been executed inside a Kubernetes container then how can we do it?

Answer (score 0):

this is possible using eBPF, there are a few kubernetes tools that can do session auditing, one of them is called teleport, which acts as bastion host for services and have capabilites to record commands that are run on pods shell/bash/ash etc...

https://goteleport.com/